# subclassing cython class: pxd file not found when 'cimport'ing

Tags: python, cython, distutils, setup.py, cythonize

I have just stumbled across some strange behaviour in cython and I am hoping someone will be able to enlighten me.

I have two packages A and B, both built using distutils because I have several cython classes (many of which wrap c++ classes).

In package A I have a cython class that I call `BaseAClass` forward declared in a .pxd file and fully declared in the corresponding .pyx. I have many other classes that subclass `BaseAClass` in package A.

Now in package B I have been able to build classes that take a `BaseAClass` member, simply by doing

```
# in package B tree, .pyx file
cimport A.stuff._A as _A
cdef BClass(object):
    cdef _A.BaseAClass my_aclass
    def __cinit__(self, aclass):
        self.my_aclass = aclass
```

and I have no problems compiling and using these classes.

However if I try to subclass `BaseAClass` in package B:

```
# in package B tree, .pyx file
cimport A.stuff._A as _A
cdef BClass(_A.BaseAClass):
    """put a constructor here"""
```

and I try to cythonize I get the error `'_A.pxd' not found`. However, if I do

```
# in package B tree, .pyx file
cdef BClass(A.stuff._A.BaseAClass):
    """put a constructor and methods here"""
```

no problem! Hopefully someone has a clue of what is going on!

Note that when I compile I pass the extra flag "-I /path/to/packageA/stuff" to make sure that the pxd files in package A are available to package B. Also note that I use a similar cythonize.py as used for scipy and that I already have `__init__.py` files everywhere and I have even tried adding an `__init__.pxd` file but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import should be written as `from stuff cimport _A` where `stuff.pxd` is a definition file in the same directory as the `.pyx` file doing the import.

The line `cimport A.stuff._A as _A` makes Cython look for a definition file called `_A.pxd` which is probably unexpected behaviour.

Cython likely should not accept an import in the form `cimport X.sub_package as Y` in the first place.

Comment: how about when you `cimport numpy as np` ? see for instance [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/numpy.html#adding-types)

Comment: I meant the form `cimport XX.something.something_else as YY` should not be accepted. The regular `cimport X as Y` works but not subpackages. Either that or correctly handle that case. Might be worth raising it as an issue on the Cython repo.